# write_timeout in IO::Socket::Timeout

Tags: perl

When can someone use the write_timeout function of IO::Socket::Timeout? I am testing following code

## !C:\Perl64\bin

use warnings;

use IO::Socket::INET;

use IO::Socket::Timeout;

use IO::Socket qw (:DEFAULT :crlf);

$/ = CRLF;

my $object = IO::Socket::INET-> new (Proto => 'tcp',PeerAddr => 'www.example.com', PeerPort => '80');

IO::Socket::Timeout -> enable_timeouts_on($object);

$object -> read_timeout(2);

$object -> write_timeout(5);

With this code, whatever value i set for read_timeout, socket is closed after that expires.
If i set read time very large value, and my code doesnt write(print) anything into socket, shouldn't it be closed after write_timeout expires?

Answer (score 0):

> With this code, whatever value i set for read_timeout, socket is closed after that expires. If i set read time very large value, and my code doesnt write(print) anything into socket, shouldn't it be closed after write_timeout expires?

These are no timeouts to determine an idle socket, but instead timeouts for actions. That is if you do a blocking read it will block at most the time you've specified in the timeout and the same for blocking writes. Implementation is done with socket options SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO so you might look up the documentation for these to get more details.